# How to filter a DataTable by values not contained in an array?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, linq-to-dataset

If I have a DataTable `userwidget`, which has the following columns:

**process_id, emp_num, widget_color**

How to filter this `DataTable` using `LINQ` according to the following conditions:

---

1- WHERE `emp_num = ...`

2- AND `process_id NOT IN (process)//process is an array of intgers`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var filtered = (from row in tbl.AsEnumerable()
               where row.Field<int>("emp_num")==yourNum
               && !process.Contains(row.Field<int>("process_id"))
               select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, `where <list>.Contains( <item> )`

```
 var lstprocessid = {1, 2, 3};
  var   rows =
        (from datatable in dtDetails.AsEnumerable()
          where !lstprocessid.Contains(int.parse((datatable["process_id "]).ToString())
              &&  int.parse((datatable["emp_num"]).ToString())== myemp_num     
                     select datatable).ToList<DataRow>();
```

Comment: @just_name - check updated answer will do your task...and you can also add other conction as you want....